# Cannot recieve Post data sent from Vue via axios to PHP

Tags: php, vue.js, axios

devs. I am running a local apache server. There are static Vue files and 'print' folder with some script. I am trying to send an http request from Vue (via axios) to 'print' folder.

I have tried to use vue-resourse to send data, but I had the same problem.

Here is a Vue method:

```
postData: function() {
      const data = {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Doe"
      };
      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
      };
      axios
        .post("/print", data, config)
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

The index.php file from print folder:

```
<?php
$postBody = file_get_contents("php://input");
$postBody = json_encode($postBody);
echo 'Post: ',$postBody, ' here';
```

Here are some screensots from network tab (sorry for quality)
I am not sure why devtools treats request like GET, but I use POST

[image]

When I log the response into console it looks like that. Here the response is actually POST. But the data is still missing.
[image: p]

Prview tab looks like that.

[image]

Request actually reaches the file, but `$postBody` is simply an empty string. I guees the problem is that `("php://input")` does not get any input. When `echo count($_POST)` 0 is returned. Thanks for any help..

Comment: Your screenshot shows a GET request to `/print` but you're using `axios.post`. That doesn't make sense. Are you sure you're using your `postData` method to trigger the request

Comment: It is strange. Yes, postData is used for sure. When I log the responce inso console it shows that method is actually POST. May be the problem is in devtools.

Comment: Make sure your _Network_ console is open, then trigger `postData`. You should see a POST request appear. Also, what triggers `postData`? It wouldn't happen to be a `<form>` submit?

Comment: `json_encode()` in your PHP should be `json_decode()`. See my answer below

Comment: `<button @click="postRequest()">post data</button>` this button is a trigger for postData. I trigger it, but Network tab still shows request to be GET. While callback function show it to be POST as in picture.

Comment: Is that a button in a form? If so, see the note in my answer about adding the ".prevent" event modifier

Comment: Thank you very much @Phil. It is very strange but, the problem was in the directory address. The GET request was made when `/print` is typed. After changing it to `/print/index.php` everything worked out and POST request was made. @Phil, edit the answer adding this point and I will tick answer as correct one.  After your tips I have learned much stuff. God bless you..

Comment: Sounds like a web server misconfiguration. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of problems here which I'll address in order.

1. You are sending JSON, not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` so remove that `Content-type` request header. Axios defaults to `application/json`
2. Axios by default expects the response to be JSON but your PHP script is responding with plain text. Change your `config` to

   ```js
   const config = {
     responseType: 'text'
   }
   ```
3. You are using `json_encode()` where you should be using `json_decode()`. The former turns a PHP data structure into a JSON-formatted string. The latter does the opposite.
4. On a hunch, if you're using something like

   ```html
   <form @submit="postData" action="/print">
   ```

   then you need to change it to

   ```html
   <form @submit.prevent="postData">
   ```

   to prevent the form from submitting normally. Same goes for if you're using a form submit button with `@click` handler. That or use `type="button"` so it won't submit by default.

   See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers
5. Your web server may be performing a redirect from `/print` to `/print/index.php`, transforming your `POST` request to `GET`. To be sure this doesn't happen, use the full path in your URL.
6. Assuming everything works in your PHP, `$postBody` will be an instance of `stdclass`, the result of `json_decode()`. Attempting to `echo` that out won't work very well. In fact, it will [trigger an error](https://3v4l.org/T7ejU) like

   > Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

   but your error reporting level may not be set correctly for you to see. See [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

   If you'd just like to re-show the JSON, try

   ```php
   $postBody = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); // returns a stdclass
   echo 'Post: ', json_encode($postBody), ' here';
   ```

   Note that the response will not be valid JSON due to your *"Post: "* and *" here"* output.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have set `error_reporting=E_ALL` but still no message is displayed. I guess the problem is that simply nothing comes into `(php://input)`. I would appreciate futher suggestions :)

Comment: @АдильханСатемиров check your browser's _Network_ console. Find the AJAX request and inspect the request headers and body. Post some screenshots in your question

Comment: @АдильханСатемиров also, if you want to see errors in the PHP output, you need `display_errors=On`. Also don't forget to restart Apache if you're changing `php.ini`